# ElseIf statement wont run the whole code VB

Tags: vb.net

Ok so I've been working on a program I'm making and for some reason when I put a bit of my code into an else if statement, it won't run the statement at all not even the original If statement, However when I put it in a regular If and else statement it works perfectly.

This bit of code works:

```
  If TextBox5.Text > TextBox1.Text & TextBox6.Text > TextBox2.Text Then 'NE
        Bearing = Atan(X2 / Y2) * 57.3
    Else
        Bearing = Atan(Y2 / X2) * 57.3
        Bearing = Bearing + -Bearing + -Bearing + 90
        If BOFF > 0 Then
            Bearing = Bearing - Math.Round(BOFF)
        Else
            Bearing = Bearing + Math.Round(BOFF)


        End If


    End If
```

And this bit of code doesnt work:

```
    If TextBox5.Text > TextBox1.Text & TextBox6.Text > TextBox2.Text Then 'NE
        Bearing = Atan(X2 / Y2) * 57.3
    ElseIf TextBox5.Text > TextBox1.Text & TextBox6.Text < TextBox2.Text Then
        Bearing = Atan(Y2 / X2) * 57.3
        Bearing = Bearing + -Bearing + -Bearing + 90
        If BOFF > 0 Then
            Bearing = Bearing - Math.Round(BOFF)
        Else
            Bearing = Bearing + Math.Round(BOFF)


        End If


    End If
```

Could be a syntax error something, but it doesn't come up with an error at all, runs the code perfectly and all that. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: In the working code, the if condition is not met so it will enter the else statements. In the non-working code, neither the if condition or the else if condition is met so therefore no code is executed. I'm sure with some added debugging efforts on your side will sort this issue out. I normally add some brackets/parentheses to the conditions to separate the conditions.

Comment: what you're trying to achieve actually?. Just explain your requirement ....

Comment: @wingedpanther Ok so basically, there are different directions it calculates, those are just 2 of them, 2 of them need to be added, so i need in total 3 elseif statements but not just 1, but this was a showcase as the code isnt working. So to summarize,theyre different directions the program scans for then sets the calculation prefrences and calculates them but it seems the else if breaks down the code and nothing works.

Comment: @MattJ try http://hastebin.com/igicorarax.vbs

Comment: @wingedpanther jesus thank you so much, you're the best, how come the & didn't work by the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `AND` instead of `&`

`AND` is the logical operator on the other hand `&` is  for joining strings

> It is the logical as well as bitwise AND operator. If both the
>   operands are true, then condition becomes true. This operator does not
>   perform short-circuiting, i.e., it evaluates both the expressions.

```
If TextBox5.Text > TextBox1.Text And TextBox6.Text > TextBox2.Text Then 'NE
       'Code
ElseIf TextBox5.Text > TextBox1.Text And TextBox6.Text < TextBox2.Text Then
       'Code
End If
```

---

*Note:*

If values of `TextBox1.Text =4`, `TextBox6.Text=1` then `TextBox1.Text & TextBox6.Text` will yields `41`

See this [`demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CxFe28)

`&` is used to concatenate two strings

Comment: In your code you could also use `AndAlso` to enable short-circuiting